# What does it mean that the Frobenius representation of a group is unique, and what are its consequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

For a [Frobenius group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group) its kernel is a characteristic and nilpotent group, the last property restricts the possibilities how a given group could be represented as a Frobenius group. A statement of this I found [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=hRe0AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA93&ots=cxaIsv6V4f&dq=passman%20at%20most%20one%20frobenius%20representation&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q=passman%20at%20most%20one%20frobenius%20representation&f=false) in Passman's book. I guess this means that the complement $H \le G$ is unique up to conjugation.

Here is an argument were this is used (or I guess it has something to do with the facts I collected above), but I am unsure how it enters into the argument:

> Suppose we have a group $G$ acting on some set $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element fixes no point or exactly $p$ points for some prime $p$, and suppose we have a normal subgroup $N$. Now suppose $G_{\alpha}N$ is a Frobenius group with complement $G_{\alpha}$ acting transitively on each orbit of $N$ (i.e. it has the same orbits). Further suppose $N$ acts also as a Frobenius group on all its orbits. By the uniqueness of the Frobenius representation if follows that $N$ has exactly $p$ orbits.

I would be glad if someone could clarify this and what exactly is meant by "uniqueness of Frobenius representation" and how it enters the argument here?

Comment: I think the Frobenius representation just refers to the representation of the group as a non-regular transitive permutation group in which nontrivial elements fix at most 1 point. Since there is a unique conjugacy class of subgroups that can arise as the point stabilizer in such representations, the representation is unique up to equivalence.

Comment: Thank you! Could you say something about the quoted paragraph, how this uniqueness implies that $N$ has $p$ orbits?

Comment: We are assuming that $N$ acts as a Frobenius group on each orbit, so $N_\alpha$ has exactly one fixed point on each orbit of $N$, and it has $p$ fixed points altogether, so that makes $p$ orbits.

Comment: Ah okay, I see, the uniqueness means that $N_{\alpha}$ is a point stabilizer on *every* orbit, okay then it is clear!