# The uniqueness of the Frobenius representation as handled in textbooks, for example Kurzweil/Stellmacher

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

As written on [Wikipedia:Frobenius_group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_group)

> The Frobenius kernel $K$ is uniquely determined by $G$ as it is the Fitting subgroup, and the Frobenius complement is uniquely determined up to conjugacy by the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem. In particular a finite group $G $is a Frobenius group in at most one way.

On the other side, in Kurzweil/Stellmacher, in chapter 4 about Frobenius groups I read:

> Let $G$ be a Frobenious group with complement $H$ and kernel $K$. Let $H_0$ be another Frobenius complement of $G$ such that $|H_0| \le |H|$. Then $H_0$ is conjugate to a subgroup of $H$.

But with regard to the uniqueness as written on wikipedia we would even have that $H_0$ is conjugate to the whole of $H$. Right? And this is a much stronger. I am wondering why they state such a weaker result. This book is a standard reference and the uniqueness is used in some arguments, for example [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564727/what-does-it-mean-that-the-frobenius-representation-of-a-group-is-unique-and-wh) of mine where it is essential that the different point stabilizers on the different orbits are conjugate in $N$, i.e. $N_{\alpha} = N_{\beta}^n$ if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in different orbits with point stabilizer $N_{\alpha}, N_{\beta}$ on each one. Hence $N_{\alpha}$ fixes $\beta^n$ in the other orbit.

Am I right in my objection? And why then they choose to present a much weaker result?

Comment: Kurzweil and Stellmacher are (very confusingly in my opinion) using a non-standard definition of Frobenius group. The two paragraphs before 4.1.8 answer your question.

Comment: Oh yes, I totally overlooked that. But they use this weaker result to prove the stronger one much later in chapter 8 of the book.